# Platform ID in SERVER_INFO_101 Structure

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, documentation

Is there more precise documentation what `PLATFORM_ID_DOS`, `PLATFORM_ID_OS2`, `PLATFORM_ID_NT`, `PLATFORM_ID_OSF`, or `PLATFORM_ID_VMS` mean?

The constants are defined in the `lmcons.h` file.

Values can be got within the `SERVER_INFO_100`, `SERVER_INFO_101`, or `SERVER_INFO_102` struct.

Obviously `PLATFORM_ID_NT` means an NT-based platform. What's about other constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Platform IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc247097.aspx)

Comment: Which constant mean a Windows 9x platform?

Comment: Win9x/Me are built on top of DOS, so I imagine it would be PLATFORM_ID_DOS. If you use SERVER_INFO_101 or SERVER_INFO_102, then you also have access to the server's type, such as SV_TYPE_WINDOWS (Win95 and higher) and SV_TYPE_NT (NT and higher).